# Django music player: models.FileField not properly passing audio file to HTML when Play button is pressed

Tags: javascript, python, html, css, django

I am building a music player as a web app using Python, Django, and postgres.

The albums are stored locally in /media. The album information is stored in the postgres database.

I have one app that deals with the database layer - import scripts, etc. The musicplayer app contains the rest of the code.

All of my database imports are working and connected to the HTML/CSS/JS. This is demonstrated when, in the browser, each page accurately paginates through each song in a given album, displaying artist name, album title, track title, track number.

The media buttons (play, back, forward) are present but when I click on the play button no audio plays.

I have spent time troubleshooting this by altering my Django models, the HTML, JavaScript, and CSS code, and the Python Django Paginator code, but have been unsuccessful in understanding where the Python code isn't connecting correctly to the JS/HTML/CSS code.

Regardless of whether the Tracks audio_file field passes the "upload_to" parameter, the audio still fails to play.

**Setup:**

*settings.py*

```
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
PROJECT_DIR = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(PROJECT_DIR, 'static')
]

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

*urls.py*

```
from django.urls import path, include
from django.conf import settings
from django.contrib.staticfiles.urls import staticfiles_urlpatterns
from django.contrib.staticfiles.urls import static

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('homepage/', include('homepage.urls')),
    path('about_us/', include('about_us.urls')),
    path('musicplayer/', include('musicplayer.urls')),
]

urlpatterns += staticfiles_urlpatterns()
urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

*models.py*

```
class Artist(models.Model):

    artist = models.TextField(blank=False, null=False, unique=True)
    albums = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.artist


class Album(models.Model):

    title = models.TextField(blank=False, null=False)
    artist = models.ForeignKey(Artist, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    release_date = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    genre = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    number_tracks = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    track_list = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    length = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    file_type = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    artwork_file = models.ImageField(blank=True, null=True)
    artwork_link = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    notes = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title


class Track(models.Model):

    title = models.TextField(blank=False, null=False)
    album = models.ForeignKey(Album, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    artist = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    length = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    track_number = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    audio_file = models.FileField(blank=True, null=True, max_length=500, upload_to='media/')
    audio_link = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

Relevant parts of:
*musicplayer/index.html*

```
  <link href='https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.0.3/css/font-awesome.css' rel='stylesheet'/>
  <link href='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mediaelement/4.2.7/mediaelementplayer.min.css' rel='stylesheet'/>
  <link href="{% static './style.css' %}" rel='stylesheet'/>

   <body>
     <div class='container'>
      <div class='music-player'>
        {% for item in page_obj %}

       <div class='reader'>
        <audio class='fc-media' style='width: 100%;'>
         <source src='{% if item.audio_file %} {{ item.audio_file.url }} {% else %} {{ item.audio_link }} {% endif %}'
                 type='audio/mp3'/>
        </audio>
       </div>
       {% endfor %}

  <script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js'>
  </script>
  <script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mediaelement/4.2.7/mediaelement-and-player.min.js'>
  </script>
  <script src="{% static './script.js' %}">
  </script>
```

Relevant parts of:
*musicplayer/style.css*

```
.reader {
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
    height: auto;
    position: relative;
    float: left;
}
```

*musicplayer/script.js*

```
var audio = {
    init: function() {
    var $that = this;
        $(function() {
            $that.components.media();
        });
    },
    components: {
        media: function(target) {
            var media = $('audio.fc-media', (target !== undefined) ? target : 'body');
            if (media.length) {
                media.mediaelementplayer({
                    audioHeight: 40,
                    features : ['playpause', 'current', 'duration', 'progress', 'volume', 'tracks', 'fullscreen'],
                    alwaysShowControls      : true,
                    timeAndDurationSeparator: '<span></span>',
                    iPadUseNativeControls: true,
                    iPhoneUseNativeControls: true,
                    AndroidUseNativeControls: true
                }); } }, }, };
audio.init();
```

*musicplayer/views.py*

```
from django.core.paginator import Paginator
from datasource.models import Track
def index(request):
    paginator = Paginator(Track.objects.order_by('album', 'track_number').all(), 1)
    page_number = request.GET.get('page')
    page_obj = paginator.get_page(page_number)
    context = {'page_obj': page_obj}
    return render(request, 'index.html', context)
```

I am unable to discern which bits of code need to be worked on to have the audio files play when a user clicks the play button.
Is anyone able to point me to places in the code where the connection between front-end and back-end is breaking down?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was finally able to fix this issue by fixing the way I passed my audio_file from the database to HTML. I had been passing a file with an absolute path name which was messing with the way I have settings.py set up with `urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)`.

In my import script, my function ended up looking something like this:

```
def get_audio(path_string):

    os.chdir(path_string[0])
    
    for file in glob.glob('*.mp3'):
        relative_path = str(path_string[0]).split('media/')
        audio_file = os.path.join(relative_path[1], file)

        return audio_file
```

This passes the file properly in `index.html` using the code:         `<audio class='fc-media' style='width: 100%;'>  <source src='{% if item.audio_file %} {{ item.audio_file.url }} {% else %} {{ item.audio_link }} {% endif %}' type='audio/mp3'/> </audio>`.

The audio now plays when the play button is pressed.